# junit issue assertEqualsd is not working

Tags: junit4, assert

I am new to JUnit. Why is `Assert.assertEquals` not working? It is working as expected when I use `System.out.println`.

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<S> but was:<null>
at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:100)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:107)
```

JUnit File:

```
Assert.assertEquals(TransactionStatusVO.SUCCESS,transactionStatus.getStatus)
```

Main file:

```
memberResultVO.getTransactionStatus().setStatus(TransactionStatusVO.SUCCESS)
SYSO(memberResultVO.getTransactionStatus().getStatus)
```

Comment: Last time I did use `assertEquals` it was working fine, so please post a [mcve] backing your assessment